# Pascal fpc_dynarray_rangecheck on recursion

Tags: permutation, combinatorics, freepascal

I have a problem with my code. I originally wrote it in Lazarus, but compiling it on fpc compiler on Windows and Linux still gives me problems. Linux gives "Segmentation fault" and windows external SIGSEV.

My goal is to generate permutations with this program. 
It is just for curiosity and learning.

Program source:

```
program CombinationGeneration;


{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

const
     K              = 6;    // Number of elements chosen
     N              = 26;   // Number of elements to choose from
     ALPHABET: Array[1..N] of Char = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',          // Elements 
                                      'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');         //

Type
   TCombination = Array of Byte;        // Combination elemnts array type
   PCombination = ^TCombination;        // Pointer to combination elements array



{ Rotate
  Rotate digits forward in alphabet.
  If last item in alphabet is reached, then rotate element before current in combination. }
procedure Rotate( const Combination:PCombination; Element:integer );
begin

     { Check if rotation is completed }
         if Combination^[Element] = High(ALPHABET) then
     begin
                { If rotation is completed:
                    * rewind element to first in ALPHABET Low()
                    * Check if the the element before current exists, then rotate it. }
                Combination^[Element] := Low(ALPHABET);

                if Element > Low(Combination^) then
                     Rotate( Combination, Element-1 )
        else
                    Writeln('The end. ');
         end else
         { Rotation is not complete and just rotate forward the current element. }
     begin
                inc(Combination^[Element]);
        {:: Write out combination HERE!!! ::}

        { If it is not the last element in combination,
            we must rotate the others after it. So go back to High().  }
        if Element < High(Combination^) then
                     Rotate( Combination, High(Combination^) )
        else
            Rotate( Combination, Element );
     end;
end;



var
   Comb     : TCombination;                         // Holds the current combination
     i          : integer;                          // Iterator for various stuff

begin
    { Set the first combination, length is K }
    SetLength(Comb,K);

  { Fill with initial values }
  for i:=Low(Comb) to High(Comb) do
  begin
         Comb[i]:=Low(ALPHABET);                    // Probably [0,0,0]
    end;

  { Calculate permutations  }
    rotate(@Comb, High(Comb));
  readln;
end.
```

It can do about 694 000 calls of "rotation" function, and then it crashes. 
It used to do about 59 000, but i made the Combination array pass by reference and later i 
made it pass by pointer.( Last edition made no improvement, or can you tell me any ?)

```
If I decrease the N and K values until the max permutations value becomes smaller
than this 694 000, then it runs perfect. No errors. 

For example let's say we have 14 elemnts in alphabet and k = 5. 
The formula is 14^5 = 537 824 . And it is generated flawlessly. 
Also full alphabet(26) and 4 chosen works fine -  26^4=456 976
```

Some output from call stack(Copying text crashes Lazarus):

[image]

So.. can you spot any errors... memory leaks, waste.. ?

Laz ver. 1.0.8
Fpc ver. 2.6.2

Thanks!

Comment: You're running out of stack space with that many recursions. .. And your code indentation is terrible ;).

Comment: Indention is sthe stack exchange. I fist included my source with a link, but someone edited it into my text. Sorry for that. 
(http://meola.eu/files/PermutationProblem001/main.pas)

Any idea how to fix that stack problem ? ..

Comment: I don't know, decrease recursions, increase stack, pass smaller/less variables... I have no idea what the code is doing. I ran with Delphi and got about 63000 recursions before a StackOverflow with the default stack space. Increased the stack about tenfold, and got about 630000 rounds before it raised StackOverflow. That's all I know.

Comment: Thanks anyway. 
I should have thought about stack overflow. How silly of me :D

One way would be to divide the work into chunks and do them one at the time.

Comment: You're welcome. This is what I find difficult with fpc/lazarus - the debugger. A good one tells what the problem is.

Comment: For the record: since r25688 fpc recognizes the tail recursions in the code above (with -O2 and above) so it will never cause a stack overflow.